# How do I implement this[ref object].get in C#

Tags: c#, com-interop

I have to implement COM interface that requires property like that:

```
public int this[ref object Key]
{
    get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

This code is generated by MSVS 2010 intellisence and can't be compiled: `ref and out are not valid in this context`

When I produce default implementation with Resharper it produces the following code:

```
int IMyInterface.get_Item(ref object Key)
{        
}
```

But when I compile compiler argues:`'MyClass' does not implement interface member 'IMyInterface.this[ref object].get'`

How can I solve that ?

Comment: Of course, sorry I forgot. The `_Item` part tends to get added in this situation. What happens if you change the implementation to be implicit?: `public int get_Item(ref object Key)`...

Comment: Also, what version of C# are you using? COM support is [drastically improved in C# 4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/samng/archive/2009/11/03/com-interop-in-c-4-0-indexed-properties.aspx).

Comment: @Adam, I removed implicit interface declaration in method and it works :)

Comment: Have you tried simply omitting the `ref` keyword (in your first example)? The runtime marshaller might be able to figure this out from the interface.

Comment: you should add your answer to this question so that others know that you solved the problem and what that solution is.